# Combining columns into one in MongoDB Aggregate Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to group by values across multiple columns?

Let's say I'm storing interactions between people by day, and keep track of from's and to's with a count as follows.

```
db.collection = 
[
    { from : 'bob',   to : 'mary',   day : 1,  count : 2 },
    { from : 'bob',   to : 'steve',  day : 2,  count : 1 },
    { from : 'mary',  to : 'bob',    day : 1,  count : 3 },
    { from : 'mary',  to : 'steve',  day : 3,  count : 1 },
    { from : 'steve', to : 'bob',    day : 2,  count : 2 },
    { from : 'steve', to : 'mary',   day : 1,  count : 1 }
]
```

This allows me to get all interactions for, lets say, `'bob'` with any one by grouping on `from:`, and summing `count:`.

Now I want to get all interaction for a user, so basically group by values across `from:` and `to:`. Essentially, sum up `count:` for each name, regardless whether it was in `from:` or `to:`

**[UPDATE]**

The desired output would be:

```
[
    { name : 'bob',   count : 8 },
    { name : 'mary',  count : 7 },
    { name : 'steve', count : 3 }
]
```

The easiest would be to create a new column `names:` and store `from:` and `to:` inside, then `$unwind`, but that seems wasteful.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question with sample output.

Comment: first, that should be name: 'steve', count: 5 in the desired output, right?   And you can do this in aggregation framework without changing your schema (although it's not pretty).

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to group by values across multiple columns?

Yes, it's possible in MongoDB to group values across different columns.

It's very straight forward to do it via MapReduce.  But it's also possible to do it with aggregation framework, even if you don't store an array of participants (if you had array of names with both participants, then it's just an $unwind, and a $group - quite simple and I think more elegant than either MapReduce or the pipeline you'd have to use with the current schema).

Pipeline that works with your schema as is:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$from",
        "sum" : {
            "$sum" : "$count"
        },
        "tos" : {
            "$push" : {
                "to" : "$to",
                "count" : "$count"
            }
        }
    }
}
{ "$unwind" : "$tos" }
{
    "$project" : {
        "prev" : {
            "id" : "$_id",
            "sum" : "$sum"
        },
        "tos" : 1
    }
}
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$tos.to",
        "count" : {
            "$sum" : "$tos.count"
        },
        "prev" : {
            "$addToSet" : "$prev"
        }
    }
}
{ "$unwind" : "$prev" }
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "1",
        "t" : {
            "$addToSet" : {
                "id" : "$_id",
                "c" : "$count"
            }
        },
        "f" : {
            "$addToSet" : {
                "id" : "$prev.id",
                "c" : "$prev.sum"
            }
        }
    }
}
{ "$unwind" : "$t" }
{ "$unwind" : "$f" }
{
    "$project" : {
        "name" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$t.id",
                        "$f.id"
                    ]
                },
                "$t.id",
                "nobody"
            ]
        },
        "count" : {
            "$add" : [
                "$t.c",
                "$f.c"
            ]
        },
        "_id" : 0
    }
}
{ "$match" : { "name" : { "$ne" : "nobody" } } }
]);
```

On your sample input the output is:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "name" : "bob",
            "count" : 8
        },
        {
            "name" : "mary",
            "count" : 7
        },
        {
            "name" : "steve",
            "count" : 5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$unwind can be expensive. Wouldn't this be easier to query?

```
db.collection = 
[
    { name : 'bob',   to : 'mary',   day : 1,  count : 2 },
    { name : 'mary',  from : 'bob',  day : 1,  count : 2 },
    { name : 'bob',   to : 'steve',  day : 2,  count : 1 },
    { name : 'bob',   from : 'steve',day : 2,  count : 1 },
    { name : 'mary',  to : 'bob',    day : 1,  count : 3 },
    { name : 'mary',  from : 'bob',  day : 1,  count : 3 },
    { name : 'mary',  to : 'steve',  day : 3,  count : 1 },
    { name : 'mary',  from : 'steve' day : 3,  count : 1 },
    { name : 'steve', to : 'bob',    day : 2,  count : 2 },
    { name : 'steve', from : 'bob',  day : 2,  count : 2 },
    { name : 'steve', to : 'mary',   day : 1,  count : 1 }
    { name : 'steve', from : 'mary', day : 1,  count : 1 }
]
```

**[Update]**

With your existing structure, here's how you can do it with Map-Reduce, but this isn't really for real-time results. It will be slower overall, but likely more efficient though than a massive $unwind operation in AF;

```
db.so.drop();
db.so.insert(
[
    { from: 'bob', to: 'mary', day: 1, count: 2 },
    { from: 'bob', to: 'steve', day: 2, count: 1 },
    { from: 'mary', to: 'bob', day: 1, count: 3 },
    { from: 'mary', to: 'steve', day: 3, count: 1 },
    { from: 'steve', to: 'bob', day: 2, count: 2 },
    { from: 'steve', to: 'mary', day: 1, count: 1 }
]);

db.runCommand(
    {
        "mapreduce": "so", // don't need the collection name here if it's above
        "map": function(){
            emit(this.from, {count: this.count});
            emit(this.to, {count: this.count});
        },
        "reduce": function (name, values) {
            var result = { count: 0 };
            values.forEach(function (v) {
                result.count += v.count;
            });

            return result;
        },
        query: {},
        out: { inline: 1 },
    }
);
```

which produces;

```
{
    "results" : [
            {
                "_id" : "bob",
                "value" : {
                    "count" : 8
                }
            },
            {
                "_id" : "mary",
                "value" : {
                    "count" : 7
                }
            },
            {
                "_id" : "steve",
                "value" : {
                    "count" : 5
                }
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 1,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 6,
        "emit" : 12,
        "reduce" : 3,
        "output" : 3
    },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but we don't store things this way, there's some duplication of records, and I would rather not convert the data model. This would be a last resort though.

Comment: I can't see a way to do this with the AF with the structure you have, but you could do it with Map-Reduce, assuming you don't need live, on-demand results?

Comment: Other than that, the next easiest way is probably to make two passes over the the data with the AF and add the sum results of "from" and "to" from each pass.