# Aggregate of different subtypes in document of a collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

abstract document in collection md given:

```
{
    vals : [{
        uid : string,
        val : string|array
    }]
}
```

the following, partially correct aggregation is given:

```
db.md.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$vals" },
    { $match : { "vals.uid" : { $in : ["x", "y"] } } },
    {
        $group : { 
            _id : { uid : "$vals.uid" },
            vals : { $addToSet : "$vals.val" }

        }
    }
);
```

that may lead to the following result:

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "uid" : "x"
        },
        "vals" : [
            [
                "24ad52bc-c414-4349-8f3a-24fd5520428e",
                "e29dec2f-57d2-43dc-818a-1a6a9ec1cc64"
            ],
            [
                "5879b7a4-b564-433e-9a3e-49998dd60b67",
                "24ad52bc-c414-4349-8f3a-24fd5520428e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "uid" : "y"
        },
        "vals" : [
            "0da5fcaa-8d7e-428b-8a84-77c375acea2b",
            "1721cc92-c4ee-4a19-9b2f-8247aa53cfe1",
            "5ac71a9e-70bd-49d7-a596-d317b17e4491"
        ]
    }
]
```

as x is the result aggregated on documents containing an array rather than a string, the vals in the result is an array of arrays. what i look for in this case is to have a flattened array (like the result for y).

for me it seems like that what i want to achieve by one aggegration call only, is currently not supported by any given operation as e.g. a type conversion cannot be done or unwind expectes in every case an array as input type.

is map reduce the only option i have? if not ... any hints?

thanks!

Comment: The cleanest solution would be to rework your schema so that `vals.val` is always an array.  Then this (and many other things) becomes easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aggregation to do the computation you want without changing your schema (though you might consider changing your schema simply to make queries and aggregations of this field easier to write).

I broke up the pipeline into multiple steps for readability.  I also simplified your document slightly, again for readability.

Sample input:

```
> db.md.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512f65c6a31a92aae2a214a3"),
    "uid" : "x",
    "val" : "string"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512f65c6a31a92aae2a214a4"),
    "uid" : "x",
    "val" : "string"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512f65c6a31a92aae2a214a5"),
    "uid" : "y",
    "val" : "string2"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512f65e8a31a92aae2a214a6"),
    "uid" : "y",
    "val" : [
        "string3",
        "string4"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512f65e8a31a92aae2a214a7"),
    "uid" : "z",
    "val" : [
        "string"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512f65e8a31a92aae2a214a8"),
    "uid" : "y",
    "val" : [
        "string1",
        "string2"
    ]
}
```

Pipeline stages:

```
> project1 = {
    "$project" : {
        "uid" : 1,
        "val" : 1,
        "isArray" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$val.0",
                        [ ]
                    ]
                },
                true,
                false
            ]
        }
    }
}
> project2 = {
    "$project" : {
        "uid" : 1,
        "valA" : {
            "$cond" : [
                "$isArray",
                "$val",
                [
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        "valS" : {
            "$cond" : [
                "$isArray",
                null,
                "$val"
            ]
        },
        "isArray" : 1
    }
}
> unwind = { "$unwind" : "$valA" }
> project3 = {
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "uid" : 1,
        "val" : {
            "$cond" : [
                "$isArray",
                "$valA",
                "$valS"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Final aggregation:

```
> db.md.aggregate(project1, project2, unwind, project3, group)
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "z",
            "vals" : [
                "string"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "y",
            "vals" : [
                "string1",
                "string4",
                "string3",
                "string2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "x",
            "vals" : [
                "string"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: impressive! gotta check this within the next 20 hours.

Comment: that's not even the longest nor most painful pipeline I've posted to SO :)

Comment: this is slightly similar (but different columns not types) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521259/combining-columns-into-one-in-mongodb-aggregate-framework

Comment: does the project1 definition actually work? "$val.0" seems not accepted by mongodb v.2.2.3.

Comment: it is likely that when I tested/ran it that I was using 2.4.0-rc1 (I've been QA'ing it) so it's possible that this only works exactly as is on 2.4 - I will try to check it against 2.2.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your schema using always "vals.val" field as an array field (even when the record contains only one element) you can do it easily as follows:

```
db.test_col.insert({
    vals : [
        {
            uid : "uuid1",
            val : ["value1"]
        },
        {
            uid : "uuid2",
            val : ["value2", "value3"]
        }]
    });
db.test_col.insert(
    {
        vals : [{
            uid : "uuid2",
            val : ["value4", "value5"]
        }]
    });
```

Using this approach you only need to use two $unwind operations: one unwinds the "parent" array and the second unwinds every "vals.val" value. So, querying like

```
db.test_col.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$vals" },
    { $unwind : "$vals.val" },
    {
        $group : { 
            _id : { uid : "$vals.uid" },
            vals : { $addToSet : "$vals.val" }
        }
    }
);
```

You can obtain your expected value:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "uid" : "uuid2"
            },
            "vals" : [
                "value5",
                "value4",
                "value3",
                "value2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "uid" : "uuid1"
            },
            "vals" : [
                "value1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

And no, you can't execute this query using your current schema, since $unwind fails when the field isn't an array field.