# With MongoDB, how can transform mixed single/array value into array before $unwind?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assuming I have the following rows in a collection

```
{id: 1, value: 1},
{id: 2, value: [2, 3]},
{id: 3, value: 2}
```

if I want to do aggregation on the whole collection on the field 'value', how can I guarantee the 'value' field is always an array before sending to the $unwind operation in the pipeline? (without rebuilding the whole collection for sure)

Please ask for clarification if needed

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980653/aggregate-of-different-subtypes-in-document-of-a-collection

Comment: I thought I'd just answered this one!  :)   Maybe it's a MongoDB homework question?

Comment: Thanks. Not a homework question though. Your answer is helpful. If a solution has to be so complicated, I would rather rebuild the schema.